# numpy.frombuffer ValueError: buffer is smaller than requested size

Tags: python, numpy, buffer

I have the error listed above, but have been unable to find what it means. I am new to numpy and its {.frombuffer()} command. The code where this error is triggering is:

```
ARRAY_1=400000004
fid=open(fn,'rb')
fid.seek(w+x+y+z) #w+x+y+z=
if(condition==0):
    b=fid.read(struct.calcsize(fmt+str(ARRAY_1)+'b'))
    myClass.y = numpy.frombuffer(b,'b',struct.calcsize(fmt+str(ARRAY_1)+'b'))
else:
    b=fid.read(struct.calcsize(fmt+str(ARRAY_1)+'h'))
    myClass.y = numpy.frombuffer(b,'h',struct.calcsize(fmt+str(ARRAY_1)+'h')) #error this line
```

where fmt is '>' where condition==0 and '<' where condition !=0. This is changing the way the *binary*file is read, big endian or little endian. fid is a binary file that has already been opened.

Debugging up to this point, condition=1, so I have a feeling that there is also an error in the last statement of the if condition as well, I just don't see it right now.

As I said before, I tried to find what the error meant, but haven't had any luck. If anyone knows why it's erroring out on me, I'd really like the help.

Comment: Can you post more of your code please? I think it would help if we knew how the binary file was stored to `fid`, and where `ARRAY_1` is set.

Comment: @Frangipanes I added more of the code as you asked, but I'm not sure how helpful it will be.

Comment: Can you also include your imports so we know the modules you're using too, please?

Comment: For a beginner, using `frombuffer` to read a file sounds rather advanced.  I haven't used it much.  With `'h'` dtype it is reading 2 bytes per item, where as `'b'` uses only one.  So for the same size of buffer you need a different count calculation.  Have you compared the `calcsize` results?

Comment: @Frangipanes For this portion, I am only using {import numpy} and {import struct} and a class I made simply to hold the data.

Comment: @hpaulj I am a beginner in NumPy, but not in Python so I have read files before, but nothing of this size. I will admit that I am changing an existing MatLab code into Python and a few commands are more advanced that I am used to.
I'm not sure what you mean by the 'b' and 'h' being different sizes. I understand that the types have different requirements, but with an if-else statement, shouldn't I only see one or the other? Do their sizes matter at that point? From what I can tell, the size is dependent on the data I have in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`calcsize` gives the number of bytes that the buffer will have given the format.

```
In [421]: struct.calcsize('>100h')
Out[421]: 200
In [422]: struct.calcsize('>100b')
Out[422]: 100
```

`h` takes 2 bytes per item, so for 100 items, it gives 200 bytes.

For `frombuffer`, the 3rd argument is

```
count : int, optional
Number of items to read. ``-1`` means all data in the buffer.
```

So I should give it `100`, not `200`.

Reading a simple bytestring (in Py3):

```
In [429]: np.frombuffer(b'one two three ','b',14)
Out[429]: array([111, 110, 101,  32, 116, 119, 111,  32, 116, 104, 114, 101, 101,  32], dtype=int8)

In [430]: np.frombuffer(b'one two three ','h',14)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-430-30077e924a4c> in <module>()
----> 1 np.frombuffer(b'one two three ','h',14)

ValueError: buffer is smaller than requested size

In [431]: np.frombuffer(b'one two three ','h',7)
Out[431]: array([28271,  8293, 30580,  8303, 26740, 25970,  8293], dtype=int16)
```

To read it with `h` I need to give it half the count of the `b` read.

Comment: I see, so I was asking for too much? I need to downsize by half the required when I use 'h'.
Could I also use -1? Or would that make it less optimized?